# Using google closure library inside chrome extension content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-closure-library

I am trying to use google closure library inside content script of chrome extension.

This is how content_scripts look like in **manifest.json**

```
 "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": [
                "closure-library/closure/goog/base.js",
                "content.js"
              ]
    }
```

I get the below error:

```
goog.require could not find: goog.dom
```

I think one option is to use closure-builder to compile content.js with closure code and use the single output file but I would need to do that after every change in my content.js.

Is there any other way to use closure library inside content script?

**Edit:**
Even when I use closure-builder approach, it does not work correctly. It is trying to look for deps.js on the domain from where current webpage came. Eg. in case of google.com, I get the error message as below:

```
GET https://www.google.co.in/deps.js 404 (Not Found)
goog.writeScriptTag_
goog.importScript_ 
(anonymous function)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use closure library in our chrome extension, we created an empty source.js which only included all the modules from closure library that we required.

Sample `source.js` (source.js goes inside myproject directory.)

```
goog.provide('myproject.start')
goog.require('goog.dom');
goog.require('goog.dom.query');
goog.require('goog.net.XhrIo');
```

Then we used [closure-builder](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/closurebuilder) on this file and closure-library source to generate a single output file which contained all the relevant source of all closure library modules we required.

Relevant command:

```
closure-library/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py \
  --root=closure-library/ \
  --root=myproject/ \
  --namespace="myproject.start"
  --output_mode=compiled
  --compilation_level=SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS
```

Note, you cannot use `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS` otherwise all unused functions will be stripped off which is not what we want.

Include this in manifest.json

```
"js": [
                "compiled.js",
                "content.js"
              ]
```

So, we need to generate `compiled.js` only when we need to include some new module from closure-library code which was rare and not every time we change our content.js.